# bash scripting - how to loop through results called within a function

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, for-loop

I have a function that gives me a list of IPs and for each IP in my list, I want to run a query. The problem I'm having is its only looping through (1) of the results and not the rest.

```
getPartition ()
{
    _knife=$(which knife);
    _grep=$(which grep);
    _awk=$(which awk);
    cd ~/home/foo/.chef
    local result=$(${_knife} search "chef_environment:dev AND role:myapp AND ec2_region:us-east-1" | ${_grep} IP | ${_awk} '{ print $2 }');
   read -a servers <<< $result; 
   echo "Checking ${#servers[@]} servers";
   for i in ${servers[@]};
   do
       local host='10.1.2.123'
       local db='mystate'
       _mongo=$(which mongo);
       echo -n "$i";
       local exp="db.foobarcluster_servers.find(
       {\"node_host\":\"${i}\",\"node_type\":\"PROCESS\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"},{\"partition_range_start\":1,\"partition_range_end\":1, _id:0}).pretty();";
       ${_mongo} ${host}/${db} --eval "$exp" | grep -o -e "{[^}]*}";
  done
}
```

So, I tried using `for`, but its only running the query for (1) of the (5) hosts listed.

I can see in my output for `result` that the list of IPs look like this:

```
+ local 'result=10.8.3.34
10.8.2.161
10.8.3.514
10.8.4.130
10.8.2.173'
```

So, I'm just returning results for (1) of the IPs it should be (5) of them because I have 5 IPs:

```
+ read -a servers
+ echo 'Checking 1 servers'
Checking 1 servers
+ for i in ${servers[@]}
+ local host=10.1.2.130
+ local db=mystate
++ which mongo
+ _mongo=/usr/local/bin/mongo
+ echo -n 10.8.3.34
10.8.3.34+ local 'exp=db.foobarcluster_servers.find(
       {"node_host":"10.8.3.34","node_type":"PROCESS","region":"us-east-1","status":"ACTIVE"},{"partition_range_start":1,"partition_range_end":1, _id:0}).pretty();'
+ /usr/local/bin/mongo 10.8.3.34/mystate --eval 'db.foobarcluster_servers.find(
       {"node_host":"10.8.3.34","node_type":"PROCESS","region":"us-east-1","status":"ACTIVE"},{"partition_range_start":1,"partition_range_end":1, _id:0}).pretty();'
+ grep -o -e '{[^}]*}'
{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
+ set +x
```

Results:

```
{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
```

I'm expecting:

```
{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
{ "partition_range_start" : 32, "partition_range_end" : 32 }
{ "partition_range_start" : 33, "partition_range_end" : 33 }
{ "partition_range_start" : 34, "partition_range_end" : 34 }
{ "partition_range_start" : 35, "partition_range_end" : 35 }
```

How do I effectively loop through my IPs? Did I set up `result` properly as a variable to hold that list of IPs?

Comment: What's the output of `${servers[@])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea using `set -x` - another good debugging tactic (that also makes reading `set -x` easier) would be to comment out parts that aren't relevant to the issue (e.g. make the `for` loop simply print its iterations, hard-code the value of `result`, etc.) to try to narrow down the issue.

If I try to replicate what you're doing myself:

```
demo() {
  local result='10.8.3.34
10.8.2.161
10.8.3.514
10.8.4.130
10.8.2.173'
  read -a servers <<< $result
  echo "Checking ${#servers[@]} servers"
  for i in ${servers[@]}; do
    echo "$i"
  done
}
```

Which outputs (with `set -x`):

```
$ demo
+ demo
+ local 'result=10.8.3.34
10.8.2.161
10.8.3.514
10.8.4.130
10.8.2.173'
+ read -a servers
+ echo 'Checking 5 servers'
Checking 5 servers
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.3.34
10.8.3.34
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.2.161
10.8.2.161
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.3.514
10.8.3.514
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.4.130
10.8.4.130
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.2.173
10.8.2.173
```

In other words, the code you shared appears to be working as expected. Perhaps there's a typo you corrected while transcribing?

---

A key thing to note (per [`help read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)) is that `read` "*Reads a single line from the standard input ... the line is split into fields as with word splitting*". In other words, a multi-line input does not all get read by a call to `read`, only the first line does. We can test this by tweaking the `demo` function above to use:

```
read -a servers <<< "$result"
```

Which causes the output you describe:

```
$ demo
+ demo
+ local 'result=10.8.3.34
    10.8.2.161
    10.8.3.514
    10.8.4.130
    10.8.2.173'
+ read -a servers
+ echo 'Checking 1 servers'
Checking 1 servers
+ for i in '${servers[@]}'
+ echo 10.8.3.34
10.8.3.34
```

So that's likely the source of your issue - by quoting `$result` (which generally is a good idea) `read` respects the newlines separating the elements, and stops reading after it sees the first one.

Instead use the [`readarray` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray), which has more sane behavior for tasks like this. It will "*read lines from a file into an array variable*", rather than stopping after the first line.

You can then skip the indirection of writing to `result`, as well, and just pipe directly into `readarray`:

```
readarray -t servers < <(
  ${_knife} search "chef_environment:dev AND role:myapp AND ec2_region:us-east-1"
    | ${_grep} IP | ${_awk} '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: thanks for the breakdown and showing `readarray` as an example. that works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

it's because read reads only until first input line delimiter "\n"
adding option -d '', reads until end of input

```
result=serv1$'\n'serv2$'\n'serv3

read -a servers <<< $result
printf "<%s>\n" "${servers[@]}"

read -d '' -a servers <<< $result
printf "<%s>\n" "${servers[@]}"
```

There's also readarray builtin which can be used to read an array

```
readarray -t servers <<< $result
printf "<%s>\n" "${servers[@]}"
```

`-t` to remove the newlines for each element of the array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that…

```
read -a servers <<< $result
```

is only reading the first line into the array

Change that line to…

```
servers=( $result )
```

This converts every whitespace-delimited value in `$result` into an array element. Effectively `servers=( <ip> <ip> <ip> <ip> <ip> )`

Comment: `result` isn't an array.